# Gradient container breaking on Mobile

Tags: mobile, containers, height, gradient

I have added a background gradient in the body section of CSS and it works fine in the browser. However, when checking on a mobile device the gradient keeps breaking like shown in the screenshots below. Can you help me? I have no idea why this is happening...

This is my css code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", "Karla", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 
  "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color 
  Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background: linear-gradient(#212121,#660097);
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Si9usHzxgFi7RoA1aOhFKhExN1V0i1Qw - Screenshots

Comment: The screenshot is missing

Comment: Welcome on SO. Add screenshots to question - not in comment.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #212121 0%, #660097 100%);